# (C) Write doubles outside the stack

Tags: c

I am trying to write numbers from type double outside of the stack but I can't quite work it out how to do it. I have tried doing it with while loop and if statements, sometimes I get only zeros but most of the time I get nothing displayed. Thanks for helping in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct element
{
    double data;
    element * next;
};
element *top = NULL;

void Get(double &x)
{
    element *p;
    if(top == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe stack is empty!");
        return;
    }
    x = top -> data;
    p = top;
    top = top -> next;
    delete(p);
}

void Put(double x)
{
    element *p;
    p = new(element);
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNOT enough memory!");
        return;
    }
    p -> data = x;
    p -> next = top;
    top = p;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter integers in stack. Enter 0 to end!\n");
    double val;
    double m;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &val);
        if(val >= 3697 && val <= 3698)
        {
            Put(val);
        }
    }
    while(val != 0);
    printf("\nStack contains: ");
    while(top != NULL)
    {
        Get(val);
        printf("%lf ", val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` and `delete` are not in the standard C. Are you using C++?

Comment: int* p = &somethingOnTheStack;
p-=1;

Comment: I am using C right now. Haven't learned C++.

Comment: What is `void Get(double &x)`?  That is a syntax error in C.  It looks like you are inadvertently using C++.

Comment: It's a function that reads the element on the top of the stack.

Comment: It is an attempt to declare a function, but it is a syntax error.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: CodeBlocks is the one I am currently using.

Comment: [CodeBlocks is an IDE.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/codeblocks/info) It supports many different compilers. It seems that you are using it with one of the C++ compilers. With a C compiler, the code in the question would not compile. If you are trying to learn C, you should set up CodeBlocks with an actual C compiler.